# How to use function to prevent duplicated record for datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I use function to prevent the same record goes into my datagridview but it doesnt work , when i separate the code out then its worked

i tried to seperate the for loop part out then the code work , but i wan to use function  to do it so the code look more neater

```
Private Sub PicFavNote10_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles picFavNote10.Click
       If validationDataGrid(lblNameNote10.Text) <> True Then
           'if item didn added to the favorite data table yet
           'add to favorite table
           addTofavorite(lblUserLogin.Text, lblNameNote10.Text, lblDecpNote10.Text, txtPicNote10.Text, "SmartPhone", lblPriceNote10.Text)
       End If
       lblPriceNote10.Text = FormatCurrency(lblPriceNote10.Text)
   End Sub
   Private Function validationDataGrid(ByRef data As String) As Boolean
       'validation on data grid view
       For Each itm As DataGridViewRow In DGTFavTable.Rows 'loop though every item in datagrid
           If itm.Cells(0).Value = data Then 'check wherter the text already exist
               MsgBox(data & " Already added to your favorite cart")
               Return True
           Else
               Return False
           End If
       Next
   End Function
```

I expected the MsgBox(data & " Already added to your favorite cart") will excecute but instead the validationDataGrid function return false value even the item is already added to favorite datagridview

Comment: Are there casing issues? I'd use something like ````If String.Compare(itm.Cells(0).Value, data, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = 0 Then....````

Comment: Or String.Equals()....but I'm guessing there might be casing issues (uppercase vs lowercase)

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On`, it's your friend. Also you have some old `vb6` syntax, specifically `MsgBox`, the newer version is `MessageBox`. You can also change your signature to `Private Function validationDataGrid(ByVal data As String) As Boolean` because you don't need `ByRef`... On another note, you are only going to check one row, one column because of your condition, you want to check `all` rows. So if you remove the whole else and set `Return False` *outside* that for each loop, it will work.

Comment: @JonKim you're welcome, glad to be of help!

Comment: Instead of looping all rows every time make a list, add new values to list when you add value. When you want to add value just check if list contains what you are about to add.

Answer (score 0):

Before you loop all rows you need to call this sub as is an efficient workaround to validate new data on DataGridView:

```
Private Sub ForceGridValidation()

    'Get the current cell
    Dim currentCell As DataGridViewCell = DGTFavTable.CurrentCell

    If currentCell IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim colIndex As Integer = currentCell.ColumnIndex
        If colIndex < DGTFavTable.Columns.Count - 1 Then
            DGTFavTable.CurrentCell = DGTFavTable.Item(colIndex + 1, currentCell.RowIndex)

        ElseIf colIndex > 1 Then
            DGTFavTable.CurrentCell = DGTFavTable.Item(colIndex - 1, currentCell.RowIndex)
        End If

        'Set the original cell 
        DGTFavTable.CurrentCell = currentCell
    End If

End Sub
```